# Is this inequality for integrals correct: $\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx\right|>\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)^2}dx\right|.$

Tags: integration, inequality

Suppose $f(x)$ is a complex-valued function of $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $g(x)>1$ is a real function of $x$, where $f,g$ are continuous, not constant, and $f\not\equiv 0$. I have a hunch, assuming the integrals converge and are non-zero, that
$$\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx\right|>\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)^2}dx\right|.$$
Is this correct? If so, I am not yet sure how to attempt to prove it, but my intuition (rightly or wrongly) is that whatever $f(x)$ is, since $g(x)>1$ then $g(x)^2>g(x)$ so that $$f(x)/g(x)^2<f(x)/g(x),$$ so the contribution of the second integrand is always smaller than the contribution of the first at any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt is to square both sides to obtain

$$\left(\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\Re f(x)}{g(x)}\right)^2+\left(\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\Im f(x)}{g(x)}\right)^2>\left(\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\Re f(x)}{g(x)^2}\right)^2+\left(\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\Im f(x)}{g(x)^2}\right)^2.$$

Rewriting this as $R_1^2+I_1^2>R_2^2+I_2^2$, then (I think I can see) clearly that $R_1^2>R_2^2$ and $I_1^2>I_2^2$.

**Update**

According to the answer below, this inequality is not true, which I can kind of see, e.g. suppose $f(x)$ were sinusoidal function with range $[-1,1]$. It doesn't take much to imagine that an integrals over some $f(x)/g(x)$ could easily sum to $0$ since the positives and negatives could cancel out, whereas $f(x)/g(x)^2$ may not integrate to $0$.

However, as pointed out below, I think instead that

$$\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)}dx\right|>\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)^2}dx\right|$$
is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality is not correct. Take, for example, $f$ to be a Gaussian function (or any positive integrable function for that matter) and $g$ identically equal to $1/2$.

---

Even after the edit, this is still false. One can find an example where the left side is zero, but the right side is not. For a brief idea that you can adapt to a proper example with *continuous* functions, let $f$ be $2$ on $[0, 1]$ and $-1/2$ on $[-8, 0]$. If $g = 2$ on $[0, 1]$ and $4$ and $[-8, 0]$, we get a counterexample.

Comment: What if $g (x) > 1$ for all $x$?

Comment: Still no. Many examples exist where $f/g$ has integral zero but $f/g^2$ does not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not sure your counter-example works out though? I get $2>0.75$, which agrees with the inequality.

Comment: @poirot Sorry, change the $1/2$ to $-1/2$. The claim is true for positive functions.

Comment: That seems to work after your edit, but the left integral is zero. Presumably I can construct similar examples where the left integral is non-zero. I'll try to construct one.

Comment: Any small perturbation of the counterexample will still be one.

Comment: Yes, thought so. Thanks for the counter-example :-)